# Draw image on canvas from image data stored in database

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am creating a persistent whiteboard app using HTML and JS, where the user draws on the canvas and clicks save, which stores the canvas image data to a MySQL DB. When the page reloads, the canvas should fetch the stored image data from the DB and redraw it on the canvas, creating a persistent whiteboard.

The fetch functions are working fine and the image data is correctly retrieved and stored in a data structure. However when I reload the page the image is not drawn back on the canvas. Specifically, when I use `imageData.data.set(latestDrawing)`, the length of `imageData` does not match the length of `latestDrawing` as expected, which I think is the cause of the issue. Does anyone know about creating new image data with pre-existing data?

The save and redraw function in WhiteBoard.js:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    resize();
    redraw();

    window.addEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", startdrawing);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", sketch);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopdrawing);
    document.addEventListener("mouseout", stopdrawing);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

});


async function saveState() {
    // console.log("before save")

    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    await fetch('/WhiteBoard', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ type: 'canvasState', data: imageData }),
    });

    console.log("saved")

}

async function redraw() {

    try {
        const response = await fetch('/WhiteBoard');

        var latestDrawing = await response.json();

        if (latestDrawing) {

            //get db data into readable image data form
            latestDrawing = JSON.parse(latestDrawing.data);
            //create a new blank image data
            var imageData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
            imageData.data.set(latestDrawing);
            ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }

}
```

the fetch function in Server.js:

```
app.get('/WhiteBoard', (req,res) => {
  // Set the content type to JSON
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  
  // Your existing query and response logic
  db.query('SELECT * FROM canvas_state ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    } else {
      res.json(results[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried creating a `new Uint8ClampedArray`, as I read another article that suggested doing this, however the canvas still did not redraw the saved images.

```
const dataArray = new Uint8ClampedArray(drawingData);
```

Comment: Saving the bitmap array is VERY wasteful of RAM and (database) bandwidth. Use existing  encoders and decoders to convert bitmap to and from lossless standardized compressed image format like PNG. Example `canvasElement.toBlob(blob => postBlob(blob), "image/png");` Existing encoders/decoders like PNG are very efficient client side utilities that will save a lot of server side bandwidth, CPU cycles, RAM and storage space.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the back end is the problem point here, although it's good to see the context and broader use case. Once you can pass your data through `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` without losing information, the problem becomes purely front end (for now--there may be API or database issues, but those are of a different nature and should be isolated from the canvas image data get/put operations).

Here's an approach to drawing something on one canvas, passing the data through a JSON string and writing it to another canvas:

```js
const canvasToArray = canvas => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const {data} = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  return [...new Uint8ClampedArray(data.buffer)];
};

const writeDataToCanvas = (canvas, data) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const imageData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  imageData.data.set(data);
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
};

const [canvasA, canvasB] = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
canvasA.getContext("2d").fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20);
const json = JSON.stringify(canvasToArray(canvasA));
// store `json` to the backend ...

// ... later on, restore it from a response:
writeDataToCanvas(canvasB, JSON.parse(json));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
```

From this, you can see the deserialization process hasn't changed from your attempt, but the serialization process has, indeed using `Uint8ClampedArray` as you suggested, along with `Array.from()` or a spread to produce a serializable array. Logging the result of `JSON.stringify({ type: 'canvasState', data: imageData })` in your original code should show that the canvas data is not making it through the serialization process.

Now, it's generally not a great idea to store data blobs in a database. It's probably better to use something like an S3 bucket or some other optimized file storage system and store a link to the data in the db.

Another approach is to use a base64 PNG, which uses much less space and is easier to code:

```js
const [canvasA, canvasB] = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
canvasA.getContext("2d").fillRect(10, 10, 20, 20);
const base64 = canvasA.toDataURL();
// store `base64` to the backend ...

// ... later on, restore it from a response:
const img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  canvasB
    .getContext("2d")
    .drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvasB.width, canvasB.height);
};
img.src = base64;
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
```

The base64 version uses code from

- [Convert and insert Base64 data to Canvas in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473205/convert-and-insert-base64-data-to-canvas-in-javascript/8489120#8489120)
- [Getting binary (base64) data from HTML5 Canvas (readAsBinaryString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685698/getting-binary-base64-data-from-html5-canvas-readasbinarystring/15685877#15685877)