# How to copy a canvas present on one webpage to another

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, fetch

I am attempting to get a canvas from a webpage and display it elsewhere.
The canvas itself is not obtainable through an url, I get the webpage and grab the canvas from there.

That being said, when attempting to display that same canvas elsewhere, it's blank.
I understand that canvases behave differently than other HTML Elements, however I was unable to figure out how to achieve what it is I am trying to do (if possible at all).

I am making a chrome extension and the concerned code is as follows.

service_worker:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(url, _sender, onSuccess) {
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(responseText => onSuccess(responseText))

    return true;
});
```

Script:

```js
await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(url, response => {
    const responseParsed = domParser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');

    const graphContainer = responseParsed.getElementsByClassName("chart-container")[0];
    if (graphContainer == undefined) throw Error("Failed to get the graph container");

    parentContainer.insertBefore(graphContainer, parentContainer.childNodes[1])
});
```

What works:

- I obtain the full webpage and am able to get the chart-container element.

What doesn't:

- When inserting that same graph onto my other webpage, the graph is empty.

Comment: The content of a canvas element is set dynamically by code in the page. It is not present

Comment: What's the data on the canvas? Serialize it, send it wherever it needs to be, then draw it on the other canvas. Serialization and deserialization are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77592106/6243352).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of a canvas element is set dynamically by code in the page.

It is not present in the HTML markup for the page, which the posted code obtains and passed through `domParser`. **You can't obtain canvas content using this approach.**

You would need access to the live DOM of the page to obtain content of a canvas that wasn't tainted. If the canvas is  [tainted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) however, you won't be able to read its content anyway.